# Is there a way to suppress adobe PDF reader API (AxAcroPDF) info messages?

Tags: c#, pdf, adobe-reader, axacropdf

Im successfully using AxAcroPDF to display PDFs in my Windows Forms Application. The PDFs are mainly generated by scanned office documents with OCR read out. Some documents contain Website links which seem to cause Problems, because when i open them with AxAcroPdf an info message will be displayed:

[image: Alert Message caused by Url on PDFs]

Translated message: The URL in this PDF-Document might not be displayed correctly.

This message doesn't occure when i open the PDF directly with Adobe Reader. I want to suppress these messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up replacing AxAcroPDF by webbrowser control to display the pdf.